# using commons-fileupload in liferay cant parse the request properly

Tags: java, file-upload, java-io, liferay-7

I am using commons-fileUpload package to write a liferay module. Following is my code. I have written the code accrording to the http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

The list 'items' is empty. I am trying to receive folder and then iterate in it.

```js
@ProcessAction(name="process1")
 public void processAction1(ActionRequest actionRequest , ActionResponse actionResponse)
 {
  HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest));
  boolean isMultiPart = PortletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(actionRequest);
  
  List<FileItem> items = new ArrayList<FileItem>();
  
  try {
   DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();   
   PortletContext portletContext = this.getPortletContext();
   File repository = (File) portletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
   factory.setRepository(repository);
   PortletFileUpload portletfile = new PortletFileUpload(factory);
    items = portletfile.parseRequest(actionRequest);
  } catch (FileUploadException e) {   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println(items.size());
  
 }

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<portlet:actionURL name="process1" var="processFolder" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 function submitFolder(){
  document.getElementById("folderForm").submit();
 }
</script>

<form action="<%=processFolder %>" method="post" id="folderForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="myFolderUpload" webkitdirectory mozdirectory onchange="submitFolder()"/>
 <!-- <input type="hidden" name="justForTest" value="100"/> -->
</form>
```

Comment: How does your HTML (frontend) side look like? E.g. mainly the form and input tags

Comment: Oh, you are right! I forgot to add it but I will edit the post

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?  AFAIK portletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir") is likely to return null.

Comment: no it is not null!